# Numericinput with filter in react

Tags: reactjs, api, input, numeric-input

How do I list the numeric input according to the allowed value in the api. For example, when 10 is selected, 10 values should be listed in the table.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add code in question, instead of images of code editor.